# 2nd spinner populates on selection of the first in xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Goodday Am New to xamarin.Android and i have been dealing with how to Populate second spinner based on first Option and yet i havent been successful. ex. i have a spinner "country" with array List i want if user selects "United States", the second spinner should be Populated immediately with states in the US. The examples am seeing are those of Java. Please Help me Out. Thank you
Here is what i have tried out

```
spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected);
        var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(
                view.Context, Resource.Array.planets_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);

        adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        spinner.Adapter = adapter;
        if (spinner.SelectedItemPosition == 0)
        {
            var adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(
                    view.Context, Resource.Array.plane_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);

            adapter1.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
            spinner.Adapter = adapter1;
        }


        return view;

    }
    private void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void spinner1_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

But the second spinner wont populate.

Answer (score 0):

Well what you need to do involves the following steps :

- Add events and spinner objects as follows :

  ```
  Spinner _spinner1,_spinner2;
  _spinner=FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Layout._spinner1);
  _spinner.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Layout._spinner2);
  _spinner1.ItemSelected += ItemSelected_Spinner1;
  _spinner2.ItemSelected += ItemSelected_Spinner2;
  ```
- On itemSelected of the first spinner enable the second:

  ```
   private void ItemSelected_Spinner1(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
  {
      _spinner2.Clickable="true";
  }
  ```
- Also update the spinner adapter content at the end of the event as per your need

  ```
   var adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(
              view.Context, Resource.Array.plane_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);

      adapter1.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
      _spinner2.Adapter = adapter1;
  ```

Comment: This is exactly what i did earlier.

Comment: didnt Work although

Comment: i am still at the question's stage. I am New to Xamarin and i have been reading through forums but none seems to help it

Comment: Are you new to c# as well?

Comment: NO and applying C# knowledge of combobox aint working

Comment: Update your code whatever you have done for this so far